# php form preg_match protect unwanted characters

Tags: php, forms

this is my php code i want to protect my form from unwanted tag for example

```
<a harf='http://anyweb.com'>Look </a> or 
<script> something here </script> or 
<?php header( "Location:tks.php" ); ?>
```

any link or  code post to my form i tried but very difficult any one can shortest and easily protect my form from unwanted link and codes.
here my tried code

```
<?
 $error="";
if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 

if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    $error = 'Invalid name. Try again';
    }
elseif(empty($_POST['message'])){
    $error = 'Invalid message. Try again';
    }
elseif(preg_match('/http/',$_POST['name'])){
    $error = 'Invalid content message. Try again';
    }
elseif(preg_match('/http/',$_POST['message'])){
    $error = 'Invalid content message. Try again';
    }
elseif(preg_match('/</',$_POST['name'])){
    $error = 'Invalid content message. Try again';
    }
elseif(preg_match('/</',$_POST['message'])){
    $error = 'Invalid content message. Try again';
    }
else {  
$name = $_POST['name'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//include('sqlconnect.php');
//$sql = "INSERT INTO msg (name, message, date)VALUES ('$name', '$message', 'now()')"; 
//mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

header( "Location:tks.php" );
exit;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at PHP's built in sanitation filters: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

So perhaps something like this will do the trick:

```
if ($_POST['message'] != filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) {
    $error="Try again";
}
```

Comment: tks i should make more better using your answer `if ($_POST != filter_var($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) {
    $error="Try again";
}`

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php
It can protect your site from scripts, tags and more
Also if You wand to block links try this:
demo for links: https://regex101.com/r/fV3pO3/1
demo for tags: https://regex101.com/r/iQ5lH9/1

Comment: i have read `htmlspecialchars` but it convert to original document non function viable code but i want protect any code comes my form return error page.

Answer (score 0):

to protect your posted data from raw HTML, probably before insertion into the database, you can strip them of tags using `strip_tags` as below:

```
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
```

Comment: tks Naija `strip_tags` is handling post only submit content removing tag but i want my form protecting tags posts before submit to database  because filling useless message to my database for that i want if content have tags return to error message .